# jQuery: stop absolute positioning of dragged elements?

Tags: jquery, draggable, css-position, droppable, appendto

I am a complete jQuery and Javascript noob trying to get a very simple drag and drop live demo working. I am getting close but my dragged elements are given absolute positioning, so they don't flow nicely together.

Markup is very simple:

```
<section class="favrecentboxessection" id="favorites"> 

    little divs with the style set to draggable 

</section> 

<section class="favrecentboxessection" id="recents"> 

    where they are dragged to

</section>
```

And my sad little jQuery:

```
        $( init );

    var $favorites = $( "#favorites" ),
        $recent = $( "#recent" );


    function init() {
        $('.favrecentbox').draggable( {
            cursor: 'move',
            containment: '#mainsection',
            stack: '.favrecentbox',
            revert: 'invalid',
            revertDuration: 200,
        } );

            $('.favrecentboxessection').droppable( {
            accept: ".favrecentbox",
            activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                handleDropEvent (ui.draggable);
                }
        } );

        function handleDropEvent( $item ) {

        var temp;
        temp = $item.detach();
        temp.appendTo( $('#favorites'));
```

I've got the dragging working, but when dropped they carry over absolute positioning (left, top, etc are set). How do I turn that off?

Comment: created on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MPy9n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add it as a child to the droppable container when dropped.

```
$('.favrecentboxessection').droppable( {
        accept: ".favrecentbox",
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
            $(ui.draggable).css({position:'relative'});
        },
        activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
            handleDropEvent (ui.draggable);
            }
    } );
```

Comment: This works great--I just added what you have for the drop function in droppable. However, I had to zero out the top: and left: that gets added for me. Otherwise works great, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using $(x).css() to manipulate CSS after the drop.....

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this from someone else's question, which also showed me how to clear a property entirely: `temp.css({position:'', left:'', top:''});` But is there a way to not have these show at all? seems funny that they're added. The jQuery example with the photo gallery doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it more complicated than it already is.
Removing CSS seems like a bad idea.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MPy9n/6/

```
draggableOptions = { appendTo: "body", zIndex: 99};

$( ".favrecentbox" ).draggable(draggableOptions);

$( ".favrecentboxessection" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
        $( ui.draggable ).remove();
        $( '<div class="favrecentbox"></div>' ).html( ui.draggable.html() ).draggable(draggableOptions).appendTo( this );
    }});
```

Comment: You could just do `html()` instead of `text()` - so `html( ui.draggable.html() )`?

Comment: I needed to change .text() to .html() so all the div content was copied, but otherwise works great. This method doesn't add any absolute positioning for some reason, while the others do.

Comment: Sorry didn't refresh the page to see your comment. Nice to figure something out myself though! :)

Comment: Its because you destroy the div with the "draggable" styling and create a new one, which you then insert the content into (html).  :)

Comment: I also noticed that the z-index is lost with this method and has to be added back.